# Selecting parent and child data

Tags: postgresql

I have an application front end which speaks to a PostgreSQL database. I'm trying to find the most efficient way to extract a structure similar to the below.

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  person_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  fname     VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  person_id INTEGER REFERENCES people (person_id),
  item_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title     VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO people (fname) VALUES
  ('Bob'),
  ('Jim'),
  ('Geoff');

INSERT INTO items (person_id, title) VALUES
  (1, 'Cat'),
  (1, 'Dog'),
  (1, 'Monkey'),
  (2, 'Elephant');
```

My current approach would be to list all of the items, then (within the application) iterate over each and run a `SELECT`. Something similar to this Pseudo code:

```
items = db.Query(SELECT * FROM people);
for item in items
   itemsub = db.Query(SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = item.person_id)
```

There are a number of reasons why I don't like this.

- It requires a minimum of `1 + N(People)` queries to extract a simple data structure. For a page containing 1000 items, this would produce a ton of network traffic.
- The application has to manually iterate over the list atleast twice more after the database, one to build the better structure and a second to render it.
- It seems like something a database should be able to do

One other alternative would be to perform a `JOIN`, but this would result in extra processing to remove duplicates in the application

The resulting structure should be relatively simple:

```
peopleItems{ 
   array people{ 
             array items{}
         }
}
```

However, I can't for the life of me work out the best approach.

Comment: There are many established solutions - depending on what you want to display, arranged how exactly. What do you want to optimize? Query performance? IO? Ease of use? And what other operations may be connected. You would need to define your desired result more precisely.

Comment: In ORM-land, this is called a FETCH join, if that helps

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I would like to be able build the structure at the end of my question as efficiently as possible. That is, I want to be able to get data from the database into that structure without secondary processing on the application side.  Query performance would be my highest priority. It's only retrieving the data that I want to focus on as putting the data in the database is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an idea.

```
test=# CREATE INDEX items_idx ON items (person_id);
CREATE INDEX

test=# SELECT person_id, fname, 
    (SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT title FROM items WHERE items.person_id = people.person_id ), ',')) AS titles
 FROM people;
 person_id | fname |     titles     
-----------+-------+----------------
         1 | Bob   | Cat,Dog,Monkey
         2 | Jim   | Elephant
         3 | Geoff | 
(3 rows)
```

I don't know what application language  you use (PHP, Ruby, or others), but all languages can easily parse this result.

I made dummy data and done EXPLAIN. The result is shown below:

```
test=# EXPLAIN 
SELECT person_id,
fname, 
(SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT title FROM items WHERE items.person_id = people.person_id ), ',')) AS titles
 FROM people;
                                       QUERY PLAN                                     

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---
                                        QUERY PLAN                                    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----
 Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..984256.31 rows=9990 width=8)
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Result  (cost=98.50..98.51 rows=1 width=0)
           InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on items  (cost=19.81..98.50 rows=455 width=16)
                   Recheck Cond: (person_id = people.person_id)
                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on items_idx  (cost=0.00..19.70 rows=455 widt
h=0)
                         Index Cond: (person_id = people.person_id)
(8 rows)
```

This query uses Bitmap Index scan, so it can be run very fast.

Please don't forget to create index of person_id in the items table.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Postgres' JSON functions for this.

This is probably not *exactly* what you want, but should give you a good start:

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
  select p.person_id, p.fname, json_agg(json_build_object(i.item_id, i.title)) as items
  from people p 
    join items i on p.person_id = i.person_id
  group by p.person_id
) t
```

The query returns one row per person and the output is something like this:

```
{"person_id":1,
 "fname":"Bob",
 "items":[{"1" : "Cat"}, {"2" : "Dog"}, {"3" : "Monkey"}]}

{"person_id":2,
 "fname":"Jim",
 "items":[{"4" : "Elephant"}]}
```

If you change `row_to_json(t)` to `json_agg(t)` the result is one single (large) JSON document.

See the manual for details on how to generate JSON results:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html